# Python 2.7 search string

Tags: python

I need to print "word001%20" and "word002%20" from "r". After "word001" and "word002" is located random amount of strings (below is just an example).  I tried to use:

```
r = "word001%20#something=637448word002%20#something=278364"
a = str(r[r.index('word001'):r.index('#something')])
b = str(r[r.index('word002'):r.index('#something')])
print a
print b
```

but only "print a" works good. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because, here `b = str(r[r.index('word002'):r.index('#something')])` `r.index('#something')` returning the index of first occurrence of `#something`.

```
r[27:10] >>> ''
```

You can get the result by using `find`...search for `#something` after `word002`

```
str(r[r.index('word002'):r.find('#something', r.index('word002'))])
'word002%20'
```

Answer (score 3):

the second `r.index('something')` will find the first one. You need something like:

```
a = str(r[r.index('word001'):r.index('#something')])
b = str(r[r.index('word002'):r.index('#something', start=r.index('#something')+1)])
```

This will find the first `#something` and continue searching after that one.

But that is not very good if you have more `word` patterns you need to find. Maybe better would be:

```
import re
re.findall("(word\\d+%20)", "word001%20#something=637448word002%20#something=278364")  # this returns word0001%20 and word002%20
```

Comment: This regular expression does not find the string which is looked for. It was asked for a match that gives `word001%20`

Answer (score 1):

Using this string splitting and `index` may work, but using a regular expression is a better solution. This one fits your needs:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = "word001%20#something=637448word002%20#something=278364"
>>> print re.findall('(word001.*?)#something',r)
['word001%20']
>>> print re.findall('(word002.*?)#something',r)
['word002%20']
```